# HTML Render Size Difference (Chrome and FireFox)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I am designing an interface using bootstrap 4.

While previewing the page in Chrome and FireFox I noticed that there is a huge difference of page size. The Chrome shows/renders the whole page a lot more bigger than the FireFox. That includes font size and all of the UI elements.

I wonder why it is like that?
and how can I force the browsers to keep one/standard size?

**Update:** I simply visited https://getbootstrap.com in both browsers and noticed the same thing, in Chrome it's bigger and view-port covers less web page. On the other hand FireFox displays smaller/normal view and covers more above the fold.

Comment: I triied out and the only difference I see is font, in firefox are lighter. In general when designing a webpage the key to uniform browser results is include a reset script. When choosing font the best is stick on the one everyone have on their pc or use webfonts that can load on any browser

Answer (score 1):

Browsers has different font-size settings. Difference is like 1,25. So 10px Chrome becomes 12,5px on Firefox. You can change this chrome/settings/appearance.

`display: flex` to the parent component, expand the the full available height of the parent.

on the parent component:`position: relative`,

on the child: `position: absolute` `height: 100%` `width: 100%`

Comment: I appreciate your help but that is not what I'm looking for. First of all I don't want to change browser settings because the users will not do so to see my website. And the second suggestion about using the flex is may be helpful but still I have countless components in the interface not just the buttons so everything can't be recreated using flex

Comment: I use normalize.css in my projects. I highly recommend to use it. You can assign default font-size .

normalize.css: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/